# Sharing settings file between projects in VS2013

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, settings, visual-studio-2013

I have multiple projects that are accessing the same settings (they were a single project, but I'm re-factoring).  What I would like to do is the equivalent of:

```
"Add Existing Item" -> "Add Link"
```

The projects are a mixtutre of both C# and VB.  When I try to do add as link, it does bring the settings file in, but it doesn't recognise it.  I actually get the error when trying to load the settings:

```
Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
```

Is there a way to tell the project to use a specific settings file (either inside or outside the IDE)?

Comment: Hi pm. Is there anything we can do to help you out, or did you find a solution that works for you?

Comment: I think I'll probably end up doing what you suggested; but I would like to find an answer to this question.  I don't see why it shouldn't work in the way that @PeonProgrammer suggested - but it doesn't.

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. I have made a mixed project, containing c# and VB but no errors here. I did find another problem when mixing: the VB project created an own Settings.Designer.vb file (while the auto-generated file is c#). This file isn't updated when updating the settings, so to make sure you never end up in a situation when one of the files has an incorrect version, I think you should use the answer I proposed.

Comment: But are you able to add a settings file as a link in a VB project and drag it into the "My Project" section?

Comment: I can't drag it over there, but I got this working: see image [visual studio](http://i.imgur.com/WlD7OTS.png).

In vbproj:
    <None Include="..\WindowsFormsApplication4\Properties\Settings.settings">
      <Link>Settings.settings</Link>
    </None>

Comment: Yes - I got that far, but in order to access it, I believe it needs to be in "My Project".  I even tried editing the proj file to see if I could force the issue.

Comment: I don't think so. I double-clicked the Settings file it in the Visual Basic project (causing it to generate code, that was the catch I was talking about) and then I can access it like you normally would.

Comment: "Like you normally would" - would be: My.Settings.MySetting - which gives: "error BC30456: 'Settings' is not a member of 'My'."

Comment: Can you try without My. ?

Comment: 'Settings' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

Comment: Try right click the Settings.settings file and choose 'Run Custom Tool' where 'Custom Tool' of the settings file must be 'SettingsSingleFileGenerator'.

Comment: That worked - many thanks for your help!  I'll award you the bounty (but please update your answer for future travellers)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I usually put these things in a common library. When sharing settings, you probably share more than just that, so combine it then. When marking the settings as public instead of internal, you can access them across the other projects.

For future reference:

The solution was to add the Settings file 'as link' to the project, right click and hit 'Run Custom Tool' where the Custom Tool property of the Settings file is 'SettingsSingleFileGenerator'.

Note that this solution is not favored, since it depends on manually updating the settings designer file by performing the above actions.

Answer (score 1):

Taken from MSDN: Add Multiple Settings

"In Solution Explorer, drag the new Settings file into the Properties folder. This allows your new settings to be available in code.

Add and use settings in this file as you would any other settings file. You can access this group of settings via the Properties.Settings object."

I have done this,and it works for me in my C#/VB mixed projects. Hope this helps

Comment: In the VB project, the settings link file is already under the "My Settings" folder, but it causes the crash mentioned above.